# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ApplicationController):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am attempting to upgrade my rails application. I've never done this before but decided it best after learning about one of the recent features that are in 5.1 (I was using 5.0.7).  I think my ultimate goal is to go all the way to the latest, since I realize that long term it is a good idea.

One thing that I am stuck on after making the changes, is that I am running into routing a routing error.

The server error I get is

`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Downtown::ApplicationController):`

When I deployed this to heroku (thought it was all set before I did so) the errors i get are

```
! Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Downtown::ApplicationController
bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin/puma)
NameError: uninitialized constant Downtown::ApplicationController
/app/app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

One thing in my routes that I had before this switch was I have some nested routing. Yet looking at the [release notes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html)  I haven't found anything that would require changes within my routes files, and the only thing in the release notes that are related are `Direct & resolved` routing which I don't think i'm using.

My routes are

```
  resources :downtowns do
    resources :properties do
    end
  end
```

My application controller is basically empty.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

My downtown controller is

```
class DowntownsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_downtown, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  ....the general def show and create files and such....

end
```

My properties controller is

```
class PropertiesController < Downtown::ApplicationController
  before_action :find_property, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  ....the general def show and create files and such....

end
```

Both of my models route to the `ApplicationRecord`

```
class Downtown < ApplicationRecord
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
end
```

My application record is below. I have it set to `ActiveRecord::Base` which i believe to be correct?

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

My `app/config/environment.rb` file fails on the `initialize!` line.

```
# Load the Rails application.
require_relative 'application'

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

I'm at the point where I am shooting in the dark here. Would anyone have any idea what I am missing at the point?

Comment: `class PropertiesController < Downtown::ApplicationController` did you mean to actually write `class PropertiesController < ApplicationController`?

Comment: Actually no. Because of the nested routing, the properties are inside the umbrella of the downtowns here.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue what your trying to say with that mumbo jumbo. Which class your controllers inherit from has nothing to do with nested routes. If you want to have a different parent class for your controllers like `Downtown::ApplicationController` you would have to actually create such a class in that module nesting.

Comment: Eg. `class Downtown; class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController; end; end` although usually a module is used (`Downtowns`) instead of using your model as a namespace and thus reopening it.

Comment: try `class PropertiesController < Downtowns::ApplicationController` instead of `class PropertiesController < Downtown::ApplicationController`. You may have a typo

Comment: you guys are all the best!!! thank you so much!!!! I was wrong with that controller!!!